# Web socket- Python client with Flutter 'server': stuck at create_connection

Tags: python, android, flutter, dart, websocket

The server is running on Android within a flutter application. The client is running on Python on windows.

The client seems to connect, but the code doesn't run past 'create_connection'.

To create the server, I use the IP of the mobile phone with the *ServerSocket* interface.

This is what gets printed out from the debug console of the flutter app, which confirms that the client does connect to the server in the app:

```
I/flutter ( 7741): Listening...
I/flutter ( 7741): GET / HTTP/1.1
I/flutter ( 7741): Upgrade: websocket
I/flutter ( 7741): Host: 192.168.100.6:5000
I/flutter ( 7741): Origin: http://192.168.100.6:5000
I/flutter ( 7741): Sec-WebSocket-Key: HdFf4BoYt+I4YOD7OPIg2Q==
I/flutter ( 7741): Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
I/flutter ( 7741): Connection: Upgrade
```

**client.py**

```
from websocket import create_connection

try:
    ws = create_connection("ws://192.168.100.6:5000")
    print("Connected")

    result = ws.send('Hey'.encode('utf-8'))

    ws.close()
except Exception as e: print(e)
```

**main.dart**

```
// import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:web_socket_app/Server/tcp_server.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {
  try {
    TCPServer tcp = TCPServer(port: 5000);
    await tcp.startServer();
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(body: Text('hey')),
    );
  }
}
```

**tcp_server.dart**

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

class TCPServer {
  late ServerSocket socket;

  final int port;

  TCPServer({required this.port});

  Future<ServerSocket> bindTo(int port) async {
    return ServerSocket.bind('192.168.100.6', port);
  }

  get getInstance => socket;

  Future<void> startServer() async {
    try {
      await bindTo(port).then((server) {
        print('Server started at ${server.address}:${server.port}');
        server.listen((client) async {
          client.listen((event) {
            print("Listening...");
            print(utf8.decode(event));
            // print('received');
            client.write('received');
          });
        });
      });
    } catch (err) {
      print(err);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `To create the server, I use the IP of the mobile phone with the ServerSocket interface.` ? To create a ServerSocket you do not have to mess with ip's to begin with. Unclear. Confusing.

Comment: `I am using flutter as the server` Impossible. Flutter is a development environment and no server. First tell where your server is running (pc, laptop or Android device). Then tell where the client is running. You could then also tell how yo builded server and client. For me all is confusing now.

Comment: How? Don't I need to bind an ip to the server? I have been referring to [this](https://medium.com/flutter-community/working-with-sockets-in-dart-15b443007bc9). But I don't think the IP is the issue here. There is a connection, but the connection hangs from the client side (python).

Comment: The server is running on Android within a flutter application. The client is running on Python on windows

Comment: `I/flutter ( 7741): Client listening...` ?? Confusing log message. A client does not listen. A server listens. A server listens and waits until a client connects.

Comment: `print("Connected")` Do you see that?

Comment: No, I don't, it is stuck at the ```create_connection``` line

Comment: `print("Listening...");` You keep it doing confused. You should put that statement directly after the server is started as then the server starts listening. And then if a client connects you should print something like "client connected". And then after you receiver someting from the client you print : "received from client...". I still dont know what really happens as everithing is too confusing.

Comment: And dont bind your server to an ip. I said before that a serversocket does not have to mess with an ip. It should just listen. Dont bind!. remove that statement.